# How do change detection strategies distinguish?

Tags: angular

According to [Angular.io docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html), there are 7 strategies of change detection:
CheckOnce, Checked, CheckAlways, Detached, OnPush, Default, OnPushObserve
I'm a noob here so it's really hard for me to understand. Can someone explain me the distinction between them. Thank you!

Comment: I can recommend [this](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2) post, which partially covers this subject. Apart of this, I would recommend reading Angular source code's documentation. I would start from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules%2Fangular2%2Fsrc%2Fcore%2Fchange_detection%2Fchange_detector_ref.ts)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710493/whats-the-difference-between-onpushobserve-and-onpush-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

Not a strict answer to the question but may still point people in the right direction:

Apparently there are **only two** detection strategies which should be used by consumers of Angular framework: **Default** and **OnPush**.
The other mechanisms are only used by Angular internally. For more details check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7311#issuecomment-189418835) thread from Angular's repo.

A small clarification which may be helpful for others regarding **OnPush** strategy:

When using the **OnPush strategy**, changes are picked up **automatically** only if the Immutable object is **updated from outside** (line 53 in the example below).
If the '`@Input()` property' is **updated inside the component** then we need to **inform the change detector** that we have changes in order for the component to reflect the new values. We do that using `.markForCheck` which [will mark all ChangeDetectionStrategy ancestors as to be checked](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) (line 30 in the example below).

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/bp00rvDgAp8ljTLJEmHI?p=preview
(updated and forked from http://plnkr.co/edit/oT8F8m?p=preview)

Play around with line 30:

```
// this.ref.markForCheck(); // uncomment it to manually apply changes
```

If the line is commented out we won't see the component updated with the values set by the timeout inside the component's constructor (line 24).

We'll only see the component updated with the values set by the timeout outside the component (line 53).

Once we uncomment the line then the component is updated with the values set by the timeout inside the component.