# What's the difference between OnPushObserve and OnPush in Angular2?

Tags: angular

What's the difference between OnPushObserve and OnPush in Angular2?
I know all about onPush strategy and Observables.. but wondering the difference between these two... maybe ng2 dev can share more info...

docs seems outdated:  https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html

regards

Sean ( Angular 2 Boilerplate App: http://ng2.javascriptninja.io)

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE 04 Mar 16

From Angular2 [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> OnPushObserve was an experimental feature for Dart and had conceptual performance problems, as setting up observables is slow. Use OnPush instead.

INITIAL

Referring to [ng-book2](https://www.ng-book.com/2/) tutorial description, If a component depends on observable inputs (streams), and change detection strategy is specified as OnPushObserve,

> then Angular will subscribe for changes on inputs and trigger an update when a new event is emitted.

As I understand it:

- OnPush strategy is used if the component depends on immutable inputs.
- OnPushObserve strategy is used if the component depends on observable inputs.

All seems clear, except that statement from current version of [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy-enum.html) is confusing.

> OnPushObserve - This is an experimental feature. Works only in Dart.